# Would a muggle polyjuiced into a wizard be able to do magic?

Tags: harry-potter

Can Muggles use magic if they drink the Polyjuice Potion that contains a wizard's DNA?

It's self-evident throughout the Harry Potter series that someone who takes Polyjuice potion assumes another person's physical characteristics, while keeping their own mental characteristics.

Suppose a wizard gave a muggle the Polyjuice potion to temporarily transform into a wizard. Would they attain the ability to do magic, or would that be considered part of their physical characteristics (which they temporarily attain)?

Comment: Related, but opposite: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147674/51379

Comment: Tempted to close as "opinion-based". As far as I can recall, at no point does a muggle use polyjuice potion.

Comment: @Valorum: Your answer to the other question may provide a basis for answering this question.

Comment: We don't see muggles polyjuiced into wizards, but we see wizards polyjuiced into other wizards, and their magical abilities don't seem to change.  A wizard doesn't lose the allegiance of his wand when using polyjuice to impersonate another wizard, even when the two have vastly different bodies, personalities, and beliefs (eg, Harry impersonating Runcorn in *Deathly Hallows*).  That's about power loss, though, not about power gain.  It'd be useful if Hermione had mentioned how cooperative Bellatrix's wand was while she was impersonating Bellatrix instead of before she took the potion.

Comment: Polyjuice is an impersonation potion, not a magicifisation potion.

Comment: In short... No.

Answer (score 4):

Well, as The Giant of Lannister mentions in the comments, simply **NO**.

The Polyjuice potion can be sort of considered as an ultra advanced form magical form of a mask. Instead of just changing the facial appearance, it changes the FULL appearance of the person(even gender, if necessary) and makes them an exact physical copy of the person. However, no *magical* aspect of the person is acquired by the person who drinks the potion. There is **no** mention anywhere of the fact that when Harry,Ron,Hermione,Barty etc. took the Polyjuice potion *any* of them acquired the magical aspects of the person they looked like. One proof of this is the case when Harry conjures a Patronus in order to escape from the Dementors in the Ministry when the trio goes after Umbridge. The Patronus was *still* a stag, and Harry was able to conjure it perfectly well, as he generally did given that fact that Harry aced it when it came to conjuring Patronuses. Moreover, when Hermione reads the effects of the Polyjuice Potion to Harry and Ron from a book(in TCoS), nowhere does she mention anything about the magical aspects being copied/acquired.The Dark Lord's comment sums this up :-

Polyjuice is an impersonation potion, not a magicifisation potion.